# Relational database with multiple preferences and categories

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to wrap my head around designing my database which will store one or more preferences for many categories for each user. So in other words, each user can select one or more options from the Colors category, one or more options from the Shapes category, and so on.

My initial thought was to first have a User table with generic user information. Next, there would be a table to store all the different categories as so:

```
CATEGORY_ID  |  CATEGORY_VALUE
--------------------------------
1            |  Colors
2            |  Shapes
3            |  Sizes
```

I'd separate each Category into it's own table (Colors for example):

```
OPTION_ID  |  OPTION_VALUE
------------------------------
1          |  Red
2          |  Blue
3          |  Green
```

Finally, I would have a User Preferences table:

```
USER_ID |  CATEGORY_ID  |  OPTION_ID
----------------------------------------
1       |  1            |  2
1       |  1            |  3
1       |  3            |  2
2       |  1            |  3
```

Am I on the right track here or is there a better/more efficient way to designing this. I will be setting up a search results page which will allow visitors to filter through these different categories.

Thanks!

Comment: That's quite perfect 3rd normal form (which is the best approach almost always)

Comment: This is fine. You avoided the usual trap of putting a comma-separated list in a column.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the feedback! I've seen this type of design condensed to one less table by eliminating the Categories table, but I thought this might be more flexible.

Comment: The categories table is needed only when you need to manage them. if not, you can omit it

Comment: If I omit the Category table, would I just represent the category ID in a function in the code?